# Shift all elements of a increasing list to another list

Tags: java, list, synchronization

I have a synchronized ArrayList which is getting it's size increased by multiple threads by adding objects to the list. I need to read this list in chunks and keep appending to a file. I need a code using which I can move first few elements of the ArrayList to another ArrayList and use the second arraylist to append to the file. All the elements of second arraylist should be removed from the synchronized ArrayList. I need to repeat this function till the synchronized ArrayList becomes empty. Please suggest a code for same.

Comment: This sounds more less like a class producer-consumer scenario.  If so, you probably actually want a thread-safe queue, rather than these lists.

Comment: Why dont you try BlockingQueue instead of ArrayList?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the suggestions given by @Novaterata and @Tharun and finally achieved this by using `LinkedBlockingQueue`.

```
LinkedBlockingQueue<CustomObject> sharedList = new LinkedBlockingQueue<>();

// Sharing the queue with multiple threads to write to it.
new ForkJoinPool().submit(() -> logicForAddingDataToQueue(sharedList)).join();
```

And drained the elements form BlockingQueue to a list and appended the list to the file, every 10 seconds like below :

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Thread(() -> writeToFile(sharedList)){}, 1, 10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

where `writeToFile` method is defined as below:

```
public void writeToFile(LinkedBlockingQueue<CustomObject> sharedList) {
      List<CustomObject> subList = new ArrayList<>();
      sharedList.drainTo(subList);
      FileWriterUtil.appendToFile(fileName, subList);
      subList.clear();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Blocking queues.

```
BlockingQueue<String> queue = new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(1000);
```

Add to queue from your threads just the way you do in your list now.

In a seperate thread do this:

```
while(queue.peek()!=null){
    String s=queue.poll();
    //Write to file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As @OliverCharlesworth said, this is a job for a queue, and in java, that is handled by the Deque interface.

You don't need 2 lists. You just need a single Deque, either a [BlockingLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/LinkedBlockingDeque.html) or a [ConcurrentLinkedDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentLinkedDeque.html)
This will handle the thread-safety.
[Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19179046/concurrentlinkeddeque-vs-linkedblockingdeque)

A deque has 2 sides that can be added to or removed from accordingly
The workflow would be like so:

```
worker threads >> deque >> file
```

Worker threads add to the beginning of the deque
The file code polls the end of the deque until it's empty and appends to the file.

```
// in the workers
dueue.addFirst(aString);


// in the monitor
String current;
while((current = deque.pollLast()) != null){
    // append to File or buffer
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will have around 100000 of strings in the blocking queue. And if I write to a file for each string one by one, it will be too much overhead because of IO operations. Any suggestions for handling this.

Comment: Just use a BufferedWriter and set the buffer size large enough to address your IO concerns. Don't forget to flush it at the end.